# Confluence - Unable to get jQuery events (click) to fire

Tags: jquery, confluence

I'm trying to use jQuery inside Confluence and I can't get the click event to fire.
Here is the code, it is in a user macro inside Confluence so I can't link directly to the page.

```
<div class="simple-login">
    <form method="post" action="http://www.google.com">
        <span class="simple-username">
            <label for="test-username">$i18n.getText("username.name")</label>
            <input id="test-username" type="text" 
                                       name="os_username" autocomplete="off" />
        </span>
        <span class="simple-password">
            <label for="test-password">$i18n.getText("password.name")</label>
            <input id="test-password" type="password" name="os_password" />
        </span>
        <input type="button" name="btntestLogin" id="btntestLogin"
                                 class="button" data-actionrequest="testlogin" value="Login">
        #if ($remember-me)
            <input type="hidden" name="os_cookie" value="true" />
        #end
        <input type="hidden" name="os_destination" value="$link" />
    </form>    
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
         AJS.toInit(function() {
                 jQuery('#btntestLogin').on('click', function(e){
                    alert('test click');
                });
         });
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             jQuery('#btntestLogin').on('click', function(e){
                alert('test click');
            });
         });
 </script>
```

I'm not too familiar with Confluence, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery on was added in 1.7.

Comment: Are these form structures dynamically added? If so, you may need to change the format of the `.on()` method that you are using. Try `jQuery('body').on('click','#btntestLogin',function(e) {` ......

Answer (score 0):

Confluence 5+ uses jQuery 1.7 so this code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     AJS.toInit(function($) {
             $('#btntestLogin').on('click', function(e){
                alert('test click');
            });
     });
</script>
```

Confluence versions below 5.0 use jQuery 1.6.4 or less, instead try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     AJS.toInit(function($) {
             $('#btntestLogin').bind('click', function(e){
                alert('test click');
            });
     });
</script>
```